# How does HTTP Debugger sniff ALL traffic?

Tags: python, http

I have written and launched a local server that runs on port 8089. Then, I set up a system proxy with localhost:8089 so that all requests go through my local server. My local server processes the requests and returns responses, meaning that all requests should go through my local server.

However, in practice, it behaves strangely:

1. When launching different applications (e.g., Discord), the requests do go through my server.
2. When sending requests through curl, the requests DO NOT go through my server. Why is that?

I have noticed that if I use HTTP Debugger, it displays all requests, including those sent through curl

Here is my code:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI()


@app.middleware("http")
async def capture_requests(request: Request, call_next):
    print(request.method, request.url)
    response = await call_next(request)
    return response


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="127.0.0.1", port=8089, log_level='critical')
```

Also it seems like response is not valid, for some reasons even when request goes through my server, response is not valid and it doesnt even have content

Comment: I've never used uvicorn or fastapi, but does your script catch https as well as http?

Comment: yes it does, but request.url is always http, like even if it catch HTTPS request, request.url will be HTTP but not HTTPS, maybe if I use flask there will be less problems?

Comment: I did flask version too, here is the code
edited: it seems like if I paste code here it will be formated very weird, so I upploaded code on pastebin - https://pastebin.com/raw/in0hTv5P


but it has same problem, it thinks that HTTPS requests were HTTP:
image - https://i.imgur.com/f6oGRIi.jpg